# Is it possible to expose docker ports to a specific interface

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

My server has two network interfaces, eth0 and wlan0, one connected to the internet and the other to an internal network. The current solution of exposing Docker container ports with docker-compose to a specific interface is to use:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mosquitto:
    ports:
      - "192.168.0.1:1883:1883"
```

This makes it brittle since the IP addresses are distributed via DHCP. Several devices are used, of which each may have a different IP address. Therefore, is it possible to expose ports to only a specific interface? In addition, everything runs on [Resin.io](https://resin.io/), limiting the configuration of iptables and co.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can address either of the two blockers mentioned as such:

With regards to the dynamic DHCP IPs, you can follow this resin.io guide about setting up static IPs: https://docs.resin.io/reference/resinOS/network/2.x/#setting-a-static-ip. After setting up a static ip, you should be able to use it in the `ports` configuration.

Another option is to use iptables, within your `mosquitto` application container. This can be achieved by:

a) setting the `network_mode: host` and `privileged: true` settings for the mosquitto service

b) installing `iptables` as part of a `RUN` instruction in your Dockerfile (e.g. `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install iptables`)

c) configuring iptables (e.g. `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 1883 -j DROP` to drop connections to port 1883 on the `wlan0` interface)

As a side-note, I'd encourage you to have a look at our community forum (https://forums.resin.io) for any resin.io questions you might have. Our user base is pretty active there and chances are that more people will have a similar question or helpful suggestions for you.

Thanks!

Comment: Related question, why are interfaces in ResinIO still called eth0 and wlan0 instead of the new mangled interface names?

Comment: Tweaked the iptables command slightly to drop everything except the packets on eth0 and use service variables:

iptables -A INPUT -i !$MOSQUITTO_INTERFACE -p tcp --destination-port 1883 -j DROP