# Use Docker container to create/delete host iptable rules

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Due to the host environment (resin.io), I need to configure the host's iptables from a privileged container. When stopping the container, the rule should be removed to perform clean up and mitigate long term problems.

The `docker-compose.yml` would look as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  firewall:
    build: ./firewall
    container_name: firewall
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
```

Creating the rule is possible with a bash script as follows:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp --destination-port 1883 -j DROP
```

The question is, how would the `Dockerfile` and bash script be structured so that the rule is removed when the container is stopped (receives SIGTERM).

*Conext:* Mosquitto is running as a service on a Raspberry Pi within the Resin.io framework. There are two network interfaces, one connected to the internet and one internal network. I would like to only expose Mosquitto to the local network. In an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304842/is-it-possible-to-expose-docker-ports-to-a-specific-interface) I learned how to do it for a single container, but it has the downsides that:

- The service in the container runs with  privileged rights
- It can not use the Docker DNS (container name as IP address resolution)
- Would be better for a single container to configure the firewall for all other containers

Comment: Can you run it as `docker` command instead of `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 0):

You will run a bash script as the main script like below

```
exit_script() {
    echo "Printing something special!"
    touch /data/shutdown.txt
}

echo "Started with $@ $$ $? $0"
echo "Setting up firewall rules"
#if you use bash then below trap command will work
#trap exit_script SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP SIGQUIT SIGABRT SIGKILL

# if you use sh then below trap will work
trap exit_script INT TERM HUP QUIT ABRT KILL

tail -f /dev/null &
wait $!
echo "The command has ended now"
```

You can see the output like below

```
$ docker run -it -d -v $PWD/data:/data exit
30e90fc4b6d6e83b39ec3489a52082ba1b4057016149c4f1b21d8cfc18d68e67

$ docker stop 30e90fc4b6d6e83b39ec3489a52082ba1b4057016149c4f1b21d8cfc18d68e67
30e90fc4b6d6e83b39ec3489a52082ba1b4057016149c4f1b21d8cfc18d68e67

$ docker logs 30e90fc4b6d6e83b39ec3489a52082ba1b4057016149c4f1b21d8cfc18d68e67
Started with  1 0 /tmp/run.sh
Setting up firewall rules
Printing something special!
The command has ended now

$ ls -al data/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 May 27  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 192 May 27  2018 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   0 May 27 04:13 shutdown.txt
```

With `docker-compose` below worked for me

```
version: "3"
services:
  firewall:
    build: .
    container_name: firewall
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
    stdin_open: true
    stop_signal: SIGTERM
    stop_grace_period: 10s
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

And the test

```
$ rm -rf data/

$ docker-compose up --build
Building firewall
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:xenial
 ---> 0b1edfbffd27
Step 2/3 : COPY run.sh /tmp/run.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4ef587c94e1
Step 3/3 : CMD exec /tmp/run.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89a57a78369e
Successfully built 89a57a78369e
Successfully tagged exitscript_firewall:latest
Starting firewall ... done
Attaching to firewall
firewall    | Started with  1 0 /tmp/run.sh
firewall    | Setting up firewall rules
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping firewall ... done

$ ls -al data/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 May 27  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 192 May 27  2018 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   0 May 27 04:19 shutdown.txt
```

You will not see the output in logs but the commands will get executed as you can see the existence of `shutdown.txt`